# Ejecutar una vez un .splice()

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo esta estructura de datos:

```
[
[{id:99}],
[{id:99}],
[{id:125}],
[{id:35}],
[{id:80}]
]
```

En el caso de que quiera eliminar **una sola vez** un array con id:99 como puedo hacerlo?

Los datos los traigo de una api, el cual voy agregando al carrito de compras y hace que se repitan los id.

Answer (score 1):

Intenté reproducir el error creando una función con tu ciclo y ejecutándola varias veces, pero siempre se eliminó solo un elemento del arreglo.

Por otra parte, puedes simplificar con [Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) para obtener el índice del elemento buscado o -1 en caso de no encontrarlo.

```js
let array = [
    [{id:99}],
    [{id:99}],
    [{id:99}],
    [{id:125}],
    [{id:35}],
    [{id:80}]
];

function elimina(id) {
    // Buscar elemento y obtener índice
    let index = array.findIndex(item => item[0].id == id);
    // ¿Se encontró? Solo si el índice es mayor o igual que cero
    if(index >= 0) {
        // Eliminar
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

elimina(99);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso yo crearía una función y la llamaria cada vez que lo necesites, incluyendo todo tu código actual.

A mi me funciona bien así:

```js
array = [
[{id:99}],
[{id:99}],
[{id:125}],
[{id:35}],
[{id:80}]
]

btn = document.getElementById('borrar');

btn.addEventListener('click',borrarId);

function borrarId() {
    let index = 0;
  while (index < array.length) {
    if (array[index][0].id == '99') {
      console.log("Se ejecuto");
      array.splice(index, 1);
      // break;
      index = 199999;
    }
    index++;
  }
  console.log(array)
}
```

```html
<button id="borrar">
Borrar
</button>
```